# WebStorm 2016 + stylelint

Tags: webstorm, jetbrains-ide, stylelint

I have installed WebStorm 2016.
Today I've installed stylelint, but I cant make it work.

I got error:

```
"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "T:/project/html/node_modules/stylelint/bin/stylelint.js" -f json
Error: No configuration provided for T:\project\html\css
```

I was trying to google about configuration file, but I can't, I didn't found any useful information or I googled wrong.

I was testing my .json config file with different names: `css.stylelintrc`, `css.stylelintrc.json`, `stylelintrc.json` and other. Was placing it in root folder, css folder. I cant get it...

Answer (score 0):

Stylelint can load .stylelintrc from root folder, but can't load ALL VARIANTS from read.me file.

Comment: I didnt use all variants in one go... Btw, didnt remember how but i solved this stupid problem.